# Serge Lang Linear Algebra Matrices p.38

Tags: linear-algebra

I’ve been teaching myself Linear Algebra from Lang’s third edition *Linear Algebra*, and I’ve been completely fine with understanding every proof, exercise, and piece of material except for this problem so far (just to give more context). On page 38, question 10, it says

> Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $^tM=M$. Given two row vectors in $n$-space, say $A$ and $B$ define $<A, B>$ to be $AM^tB$. (Identify a $1\times 1$ matrix with a number). Show that the conditions of a scalar product are satisfied, except possibly the condition concerning positivity. Give an example of a matrix $M$ and vectors $A, B$ such that $AM^tB$ is negative.

My issue is that I’m not too sure by what he means by “conditions of a scalar product” in this context. I know that the positivity condition he’s bringing up is the fact that the scalar product of an n-tuple $A\in K^n$ with itself (for some field $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$) is $\geq 0$, with equality when $A=O$.
I don’t really understand the question so it isn’t that I don’t know how to do it. I just want to know literally what to do for this exercise since the wording is weird to me in that regard. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably Lang previously defines what a scalar product is.  If he doesn't, it probably means show that $\langle A, B \rangle$ is a symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: Lang defines the general notion of a scalar product, as well as the positivity condition, at the beginning of Chapter V. He should have provided a forward reference in this exercise, as he does elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Throughout this answer, let $V$ denote a vector space over some complex field $F$.

(**DEFINITION**) We say that $\mathcal{B}:V\times V\rightarrow F$ is a scalar product on $V$ if and only if $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies the three conditions listed below:

(**SP1**) For all $v,w\in V$, we have $\mathcal{B}(v,w)=\mathcal{B}(w,v)\space$.

(**SP2**) For all $u,v,w\in V$, we have $\mathcal{B}(u+v,w)=\mathcal{B}(u,w)+\mathcal{B}(v,w)\space.$

(**SP3**) For all $v,w\in V$ and $\lambda\in F$, we have $\mathcal{B}(\lambda v, w)=\lambda\mathcal{B}(v,w)\space$.

In other words, as @D_S had noted, a scalar product is simply a symmetric bilinear form. Furthermore, notice how the "positivity condition" is not a part of this definition of scalar product; we nevertheless say that a scalar product is positive definite if it satisfies the condition concerned with positivity.

Comment: I believe the OP was only confused about Lang's meaning, and was not looking for a solution to the exercise. Also, it may be slightly confusing that your properties **SP 1-3** don't have the same numbering as Lang's.

Comment: @blargoner You have raised a valid point, in accordance with which I have already redacted my response. Thank you for your contribution.